# Convert a string to show an image of the same name using UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift

I have a plist with questions, answers and card names(eg As, 2c etc) as strings.

I would like to use the text in a string eg As (Ace of Spades) and show the image of As.png in a UIImageView (or any method really)

My code to pull the current string is;

```
boardCard1.text = currentQuestion.boardcard1
boardCard2.text = currentQuestion.boardcard2
```

This pulls the card names string fine, but how can I convert this to the image filename and have the image display?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

edit:

The images are saved in the a folder in the app - Resources\Images\4 color Deck Cards\

plist looks like :

```
        <dict>
        <key>Scenario</key>
        <string>some scenario text</string>
        <key>BoardCard1</key>
        <string>6d</string>
        <key>BoardCard2</key>
        <string>5c</string>
        <key>BoardCard3</key>
        <string>4c</string>
        <key>Explanation</key>
        <string>some explanation text</string>
        <key>Answers</key>
        <array>
            <string>64</string>
            <string>65, 64 &amp; 54</string>
            <string>54</string>
            <string>65 &amp; 54</string>
            <string>65</string>
            <string>65 &amp; 64</string>
        </array>
        <key>CorrectAnswer</key>
        <string>65</string>
        <key>Question</key>
        <string>some Question text</string>
        </dict>
```

Comment: Where are your images saved? In assets catalogue?

Comment: Can you show the structure of your plist?

Comment: @DaveDempsey Don't post details in comments. [Edit] your question with all relevant information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use String interpolation to include the current value of a variable in a String. Then you can use `UIImage(named:)` to initialize a `UIImage` from an image that is stored in your assets catalogue or just as part of your project.

```
let image = UIImage(named: "\(currentQuestion.boardcard1)")
```